# Color Style Textblock

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this **textblock** with default foreground color is white

```
 <TextBlock Text="First Cmd" Grid.Row="0" TextAlignment="Center"  Margin="4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" Style="{DynamicResource ABC}">
       <TextBlock.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding  Command="{Binding AAA}" MouseAction="LeftClick" />
       </TextBlock.InputBindings>
 </TextBlock>
```

When the mouse is over the textblock, the forground color must change in black, but this **Style** doesn't work. Why ?

```
<Style x:Key="ABC" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property ="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property= "Foreground" Value="Black">
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set the `Foreground` for `TextBlock` locally, so the `Trigger` setter cannot override that. You need to use a Style setter to set the initial Foreground:

```
<Style x:Key="ABC" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property ="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
        <Setter Property= "Foreground" Value="Black">
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The `Foreground="White"` should be removed from the `<TextBlock ...`.

Understand more about [Dependency Property Value Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms743230(v=vs.100).aspx).